# nav bar dissapears(in full size window) after using the menu button in mobile size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been following a tutorial about nav bars and everything is good except when I make the window small and try the menu button and re-scale the window to normal size everything disappears.

I've tried adding an if statement in the JavaScript but that doesn't solve the problem.

https://codepen.io/diegopiscoya/pen/yZJWBy

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".menu").click(function(){
    $("nav").slideToggle(500);
  })
})
</script>
```

I expected the script to work only when the window size is `<900` but it works always, so when the menu button hides the nav bar it does it in full size as well.

Comment: Welcome to SO! So what happens when you do the exact same resize thing with the final product of the tutorial code (not your code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, let's understand what is happening on the code...

When `$(".menu").click(...)` is triggered, it fires `$("nav").slideToggle(500);`, the slide toggle method on its final action will add a inline css property on the `nav` element, it will be `display: block;` if `nav` was hidden, or `display: none` if `nav` was displayed.

Then when you open and close the mobile menu and you re-scale the window wider than 900px, the inline `display: none` still on the `nav`, so it is not displaying because the inline CSS is in effect.

**The solution would be:**

A workaround you can do is to "force" the CSS to apply `display:block` to your `nav` if the window is wider than 900px, by using the `@media` and setting the `!important` rule.

So:

```
@media(min-width: 901px) {
    nav#navegacion {
      display: block !important;
    }
}
```

This is a CSS solution, of course there is many different ways to do it by the CSS and Javascript. But I believe that is a simple one.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".menu").click(function(){
                $("nav").slideToggle(500);
            })
        })
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: "Bree serif", serif;
}
#navegacion{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.logo{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    float: left;
}
#nav-list{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: right;
}
#nav-list li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    transition: .5s;
}
#nav-list li a{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav_li:hover{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.089);   
}
.resp-menu{
    width: 100%;
    background:#fff;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: none;
}
.resp-menu a{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px 0;
    float: left;
}
.resp-menu h4{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
    background: yellow;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
}
@media(max-width: 900px)
{
    #navegacion{
        display: none;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .resp-menu{
        display: block;
    }
    .logo{
        display: none;
        float: none;
    }
    #nav-list{
        float: none;
        display: block;
    }
    #nav-list li{
        display: block;
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(12, 8, 8, 0.1);
    }
    .resp-menu a{
        display: block;
    }
}
@media(min-width: 901px) {
    nav#navegacion {
      display: block !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, 
    user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>

<body>
    <nav id="navegacion">
        <a href="#"class="logo"><img src="wilphar_logo2.png" width="70"></a>
        <ul id="nav-list">
            <li class="nav_li"><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
            <li class="nav_li"><a href="#">Nosotros</a></li>
            <li class="nav_li"><a href="#">Productos</a></li>
            <li class="nav_li"><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
    </nav>
    <div class="resp-menu">
        <a href="#"class="logo"><img src="wilphar_logo2.png" width="70"></a>
        <h4 class="menu">menu</h4>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```